# how to write the object retrieved from s3 to a file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3

I am playing with encrypting the data before sending it to amazon s3. Here is the sample code which i have altered a bit to encrypt and upload mp3 file.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Encryption.html

```
require 'openssl'
key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(1024)

# encryption client
s3 = Aws::S3::Encryption::Client.new(encryption_key: key)

# round-trip an object, encrypted/decrypted locally
s3.put_object(bucket:'aws-sdk', key:'secret', body: open('song.mp3'))
s3.get_object(bucket:'aws-sdk', key:'secret').body.read
```

How can i get_object and write it to a file so that the original mp3 can be retrieved?

Comment: Simply writing a binary file doesn't work?

Comment: can you provide sample code plz? sorry i am newbie on ruby.

Comment: thanks hjpotter92. That worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring [my comment from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48125634/how-to-write-the-object-retrieved-from-s3-to-a-file#comment83227916_48125634) before, since the `Aws::S3::Encryption::Client` is a derived class from [`Aws::S3::Client#get_object`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#get_object-instance_method), you can provide all parameters that the latter accepts. One of which allows for directly writing file to disk:

```
# stream object directly to disk
resp = s3.get_object(
  response_target: '/path/to/file',
  bucket: 'bucket-name',
  key: 'object-key')
```

Answer (score 2):

ok got it to work with this code

```
  IO.write('testing.mp3', s3e.get_object(bucket:'aws-sdk', key:'secret').body.read)
```

it will write to a new file testing.mp3. Thanks!